# Reconnection to xmpp server using smack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, reconnect

i am trying to develop a chat app, everything is working fine when internet is stable. like i can send and receive messages. but when the internet goes off for a while xmpp closes the connection. when internet comes back i am trying to reconnect to server. after successful reconnection i got  the Stream error of **`Client already logged in`**  and connection is automatically closed.

Here is my Broadcast receiver code to check Internet connection.

```
networkReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver (){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //super.onReceive(context, intent);
            if(intent.getExtras()!=null) {
                NetworkInfo ni=(NetworkInfo) intent.getExtras().get(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                if(ni!=null && ni.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    enableChat();
                }
            }
           else if(intent.getExtras().getBoolean(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY,Boolean.FALSE)) {
                disableChat();
            }
            else{
                disableChat();
            }
        }

    };
```

here is the code for enabling chat and disabling chat.

```
public static void disableChat() {

    msg_edittext.setClickable(false);
    sendButton.setClickable(false);
    form.setClickable(false);

    msg_edittext.setEnabled(false);
    sendButton.setEnabled(false);
    form.setEnabled(false);
    showNoInternetView();
    if (xmpp.getConnection()!=null)
    xmpp.getConnection().disconnect();

}

public static void showNoInternetView() {
    linrNoInternet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    msgListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public static void showInternetView() {
    linrNoInternet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    msgListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
    public static void enableChat() {
    msg_edittext.setClickable(true);
    sendButton.setClickable(true);
    form.setClickable(true);

    showInternetView();

    msg_edittext.setEnabled(true);
    sendButton.setEnabled(true);
    form.setEnabled(true);
    xmpp.connect("reconnect..");

}
```

while trying to reconnect the error log it shows is..

```
07-04 10:25:52.880 8581-8612/com.vario.community D/xmpp: Authenticated!
07-04 10:25:52.880 8581-9732/com.vario.community D/SMACK: SENT (0): <iq     id='BpGkK-5' type='get'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'></query></iq>
07-04 10:25:52.882 8581-8612/com.vario.community D/SMACK: XMPPConnection  authenticated (0)
07-04 10:25:52.882 8581-8612/com.vario.community I/LOGIN: Yey! We're connected to the Xmpp server!
07-04 10:25:52.883 8581-8612/com.vario.community D/SMACK: XMPPConnection connected (0)
07-04 10:25:52.883 8581-9732/com.vario.community D/SMACK: SENT (0):  <presence id='BpGkK-6'><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1'  node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack'  ver='E6FpoDPmjMQ3i53V+HWh0YBrS7U='/></presence>
07-04 10:25:52.884 8581-9732/com.vario.community D/SMACK: SENT (0): <iq id='BpGkK-18' type='set'><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'></bind></iq>
07-04 10:25:52.885 8581-9732/com.vario.community D/SMACK: SENT (0): <r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>
07-04 10:25:52.886 8581-9732/com.vario.community D/SMACK: SENT (0): <iq id='BpGkK-20' type='get'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'></query></iq>
07-04 10:25:52.886 8581-8612/com.vario.community E/(reconnect..): SMACKException: Client is already logged in
07-04 10:25:52.888 8581-9732/com.vario.community D/SMACK: SENT (0): <presence id='BpGkK-21'><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='JcQq0xyVq6PbVQSN9PSQq58gxiQ='/></presence>
07-04 10:25:52.890 8581-8581/com.vario.community V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()
07-04 10:25:52.893 8581-9732/com.vario.community D/SMACK: SENT (0): <presence id='BpGkK-22' type='unavailable'><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='JcQq0xyVq6PbVQSN9PSQq58gxiQ='/></presence>
07-04 10:25:52.893 8581-9732/com.vario.community D/SMACK: SENT (0): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='0'/>
07-04 10:25:52.894 8581-9732/com.vario.community D/SMACK: SENT (0): </stream:stream>

07-04 10:25:57.935 8581-9032/com.vario.community E/Roster: Exception reloading roster
                                                       org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: IQReplyFilter: iqAndIdFilter (AndFilter: (OrFilter: (IQTypeFilter: type=error, IQTypeFilter: type=result), StanzaIdFilter: id=BpGkK-20)), : fromFilter (OrFilter: (FromMatchesFilter (full): null, FromMatchesFilter (bare): darshan350@vario.fitness, FromMatchesFilter (full): vario.fitness)).
                                                           at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection$6.run(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:1443)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

So, if anyone knows the process of proper reconnection please help me. i have searched for this question but i haven't got the solution yet.

thanks :)

Comment: I think it might be your xmpp server issue.In your server should check the client availability using presence iq based on some time interval.If client not responed then server should change the client status into offline.If client is connected in between  that duration server should allow the reconnection mechanism.Kindly check your server database once again.

Comment: i didn't get you. you are saying that once client closes the connection, server should change the presence status right?.. if that then i tried sending the status unavailable before disconnecting in case of internet failure. but it also gives me error  of No response from server and not connected to server

Comment: Plz check a both client and server side this issue then only it could be resolved.For example server should always check the client availability using  presence stanza based on the server request client should send the response to server then only server should maintain client  login session status.If suppose some clients not responding the server ping then server  automatically close that client login session .So this the  main beauty of xmpp server then only most of the chat apps using this xmpp protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a known bug in Smack: [SMACK-725](https://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-725).

Note that I don't recommend using ReconnectionManager on Android. Instead I suggest to implement your own reconnection logic tailed for a mobile environment and exploiting the information Android provides (e.g. listening for the CONNECTIVITY_CHANGED intent).

Comment: thanks,i will have a look at it. but whats the alternative? how should i reconnect then?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i will try to implement an alternative.

Comment: hey @Flow since the issue is resolved now, do we still need to write the reconnection logic ourselves.

Comment: Yes, Smack's ReconnectionManager is not tailored for Android.